# How to do integration test with MediatR using Moq in C#?

Tags: c#, api, integration-testing, moq, mediatr

I am new to Integration test, I have a controller which has IMediator and I am using Moq framework for the integration test.

The issue I am having is that I keep getting null in the response when trying to mock MediatR. Before trying to mock MediatR, I tried to mock a service (in this case IUserService) and it worked perfectly (the return type for the Delete controller and other methods was bool).

Since I am now using IMediator in the controller so trying to change the integration test to mock MediatR, I can do integration test for the handler which has IUserService but I am trying to test the whole pipeline. Below is what I have in terms of code starting from the controller to the integration test.

```
//Controller

private IMediator _mediator;

public UserController(IMediator mediator)
        
{
   _mediator = mediator;       
}

    
[HttpDelete("{id}")]        
public async Task<ActionResult<Result<Unit>>> DeleteUser(int id)
        
{
  return await _mediator.Send(new DeleteUserCommand { UserId = id });     
}
```

```
public class DeleteUserCommand : IRequest<Result<Unit>> {public int UserId { get; set; }}
```

```
//Command handler

 public class DeleteUserCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<DeleteUserCommand, Result<Unit>>
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public DeleteUserCommandHandler(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        public async Task<Result<Unit>> Handle(DeleteUserCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await _userService.DeleteUser(request.UserId);
        }
    }
```

```
//Service layer

public async Task<Result<Unit>> DeleteUser(int userId)
        
{
    var userExist = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);

    if (userExist == null) return Result<Unit>.Failure("User Id doesn't exsist");

    _context.Remove(userExist);

    var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

    return Result<Unit>.Success(Unit.Value);
}
```

```
//Integration test 

 [TestFixture]
    public class UserControllerTests
    {
        private readonly Mock<IMediator> _mockMediator;
        private UserController _userController;

        public UserControllerTests()
        {
            _mockMediator = new Mock<IMediator>();
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task DeleteUser_NotSuccessful_NoIdDeleted()
        {
            Result<Unit> expected = new Result<Unit>();
            _mockMediator.Setup(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<DeleteUserCommand>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(expected));

            _userController = new UserController(_mockMediator.Object);

            var result = await _userController.DeleteUser(6);

            Assert.AreEqual("User Id doesn't exsist", result?.Value?.Error);
        }
    }
```

//Response in the integration test

I have two UserIds 6 and 7

UserId 6: doesn't exsist so I am expecting a message saying id doesn't exsist but the current response I am getting is null.

UserId 7: does exsist and expecting something like IsSuccess: true which is a custom code I added

Note: the attached code for the test is just for user Id 6.

You might notice in the code above starting from the controller, part of the return type is Result which is a custom class I added and below is the code.

```
 public class Result<T>
    {
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public string Error { get; set; }
        public static Result<T> Success(T value) => new Result<T> { IsSuccess = true, Value = value };
        public static Result<T> Failure(string error) => new Result<T> { IsSuccess = false, Error = error };
    }
```

`

I am trying to find out what I have done wrong with mocking MediatR and why it keep returning null.

Thanks for the help in advance.

First thing I tried to do integration test mock the IUserService then switched to IMediator then started to get null in the response when doing integration test. I tried to google the issue but no luck.

Comment: The setup of the mock does not match the assertion. That observation aside, "integration test" was mentioned yet the test code still looks like an isolated unit test. Please clarify if the intention was to have an actual `DeleteUserCommandHandler` instance invoked while exercising the test.

Comment: Hi, I am new to integration test, I have DeleteUserCommand and the handler  DeleteUserCommandHandler, in my understanding I should use DeleteUserCommand? thank you 

Below is the code for DeleteUserCommand

public class DeleteUserCommand : IRequest<Result<Unit>> 

{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}